# Find minimum covering circle for given points (long,lat)

Tags: latitude-longitude, extents, circle

I need to be able to calculate a bounding box or circle for given points (latitude and WGS84 longitude).

Would it be possible for someone to give me some pointers / Example on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: You have not told us what GIS software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArcGIS Desktop, try the [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) tool:

> Creates a feature class containing polygons which represent a
>   specified minimum bounding geometry enclosing each input feature or
>   each group of input features.